# Maven does not replace a variable in 'settings.xml' when it is invoked

Tags: maven-2

I have defined a local mirror for all repositories in the settings.xml file:

```
<mirror>
  <id>myMirror</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <url>file://${mypath}/maven/.m2/repository</url>
</mirror>
```

I want that my mirror to point to a local path, in this case the path is:

```
file://${mypath}/maven/.m2/repository
```

Where ${mypath} is a variable that I pass when I invoke Maven:

```
 mvn -Dmypath="/D:/test" package
```

The problem is that Maven does not replace the variable when it is invoked. I can see that this error is happening by inspection of the build log. For example, Maven reports that it is downloading a file from file://${mypath}/maven/.m2/repository when the correct would be file:///D:/test/maven/.m2/repository.

I have also noted that Maven replaces correctly my variable when it is inserted in the url child tag of the repository tag:

```
<repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://${mypath}/maven/.m2/repository</url>
</repository>
```

The build works correctly when I replace the variable in my settings.xml by the complete URL like in the example below:

```
<mirror>
        <id>myMirror</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>file:///D:test/maven/.m2/repository</url>
</mirror>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Property substitution into settings.xml doesn't work as you would expect.

It will substitute properties inside the profiles element (as you've seen it substitutes into your repository url, which would be defined inside a profile), but not to elements outside of profiles (as you've seen happening in the mirrors section). This [distinction](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles) is made because the profile element in the settings.xml is a truncated version of the pom.xml profile element. It is a mechanism to allow configuration to be set into your POM, so property substitution is allowed within the profiles elements as they are effectively part of the POM.

The parts of the settings outside of the profiles element represent the platform configuration, these aren't supposed to be affected by individual builds, so are not substituted for command-line properties. This makes sense but isn't really made clear anywhere.

**EDIT:** in [the settings page](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Quick_Overview) of mavens documentation, in the last sentence of the quick overview section (quite hidden) it states:

> Note that properties defined in profiles within the settings.xml cannot be used for interpolation.

---

There is a workaround though, you can substitute *environment variables* into the settings.xml. If you set the environment variable:

```
set M2_MIRROR=D:\test
```

and configure the repository url as follows:

```
<url>file://${M2_MIRROR}/maven/.m2/repository</url>
```

Then invoke Maven as normal, the environment variable is substituted and your build should work as required.

Comment: Is it not supposed to be `${env.M2_MIRROR}`.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question now, but as of Maven 3, and probably before, you can refer to environment vars, if you prefix with '`env`'

I do so like this:

```
  <localRepository>${env.M2_LOCAL_REPO}</localRepository>
```

Then each developer sets `M2_LOCAL_REPO` to an appropriate location.

Answer (score 3):

I had a slightly different experience here from [Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123582/rich-seller)'s answer, so I think it's worth mentioning in a different one.

Variable substitution does indeed work inside a profile, but it seems to fail if you need them replaced before parent pom resolution happens.

I had the following configuration here:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>company-dev</id>
    <properties>
      <company.repo.deployment.endpoint>https://companyartifacts.jfrog.io/companyartifacts</company.repo.deployment.endpoint>
      <company.repo.download.endpoint>https://companyartifacts.jfrog.io/companyartifacts</company.repo.download.endpoint>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
      ...
      <repository>
        <id>company-repo-snap</id>
        <name>libs-snapshots</name>
        <url>${company.repo.download.endpoint}/libs-snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    </pluginRepositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

It's been like that for years now, every place where I use `company.repo.download.endpoint` var seems to work great until I needed it to resolve a parent pom like this:

```
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.jcompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
        <version>5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ...
</project>
```

Then, I started having this exception, even running something as simple as `mvn -X help:effective-pom` only:

(notice variables are not replaced in URL)

```
[ERROR]   The project com.company.jcompany:persistence-api:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jcompany_persistence_api-trunk/workspace/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact com.company.jcompany:persistence:pom:5-SNAPSHOT from/to company-repo-snap (${company.repo.download.endpoint}/libs-snapshots): No connector available to access repository company-repo-snap (${company.repo.download.endpoint}/libs-snapshots) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact com.company.jcompany:persistence:pom:5-SNAPSHOT from/to company-repo-snap (${company.repo.download.endpoint}/libs-snapshots): No connector available to access repository company-repo-snap (${company.repo.download.endpoint}/libs-snapshots) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:813)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:664)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:232)
```

The only reasonable explanation I find for this problem is that parent pom resolution happens so early in the process that variables are not replaced yet. When I don't have to fetch snapshots for parent poms, then all variables are replaced successfully, as expected. Not sure if I should report this as a bug.

Using Maven 3.6.3 at time of answer, if that matters.

Comment: That's exactly the issue I am currently investigating. I think that's a bug. Did you find a workaround for that ? What I found out is that the behavior is different when you inject the variable from the command line or through the .mvn/maven.config file. That's not ideal for me, as I am looking for a way to share properties among different projects.

Comment: It seems a bug to me, but I didn't have enough time to report a proper issue. Unfortunately, maven tech is not a priority to me anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The settings.xml is not interpolated like the pom is, so the property can't be used like shown above.

Comment: Yes it can. As I have said in the question I was able to insert the variable in the url tag nested in the repository tag. Note that this repository tag that I have mentioned is inside the 'settings.xml' file and not inside a pom file.

Comment: Sorry I misread. The profile portion is interpolated but not all of the "base" settings are, for example it doesn't work out well if you try to use a property for your local Repository either.

Comment: This is correct, but its not clear from your answer why you can't set properties outside of the profiles element, I've attempted to elaborate with my answer

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a bug - unfortunately property replacement does not seem to be consistent across Maven plugins.  I have encountered a bug myself around specifying more than two properties in a configuration item in another plugin.