# Reindexing local Maven Repo in fresh Eclipse install fails with java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Having a completely fresh install of **Eclipse for EE** Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0) on Win10 whenever I try to reindex it via the preferences dialog I get the following error:

```
Reindexing error
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
```

[image: Eclipse Error Screenshot with settings shown]

I already tried:

- moving the Maven repo to a fresh and/or empty location
- starting with a fresh eclipse install and fresh workspace folder
- restarting the system and installing a fresh eclipse, eclipse workspace and maven repo

Any ideas on what to check or where to look besides doing a full reinstall of the OS would be greatly appreciated.

---

Here is the full Stack trace for the error from the m2e log (as requested by @nitind ):

```
2021-03-02 16:02:18,461 [Worker-10: Indexing Local Repository...] ERROR o.e.m.c.i.i.nexus.NexusIndexManager - Unable to re-index workspace://
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException: null
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:229)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:123)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1297)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1178)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.unlockForcibly(DefaultIndexingContext.java:927)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.prepareIndex(DefaultIndexingContext.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.purge(DefaultIndexingContext.java:612)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.NexusIndexManager.purgeCurrentIndex(NexusIndexManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.NexusIndexManager.reindexWorkspace(NexusIndexManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.NexusIndexManager.updateIndex(NexusIndexManager.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.NexusIndex.updateIndex(NexusIndex.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.preferences.MavenSettingsPreferencePage$2.runInWorkspace(MavenSettingsPreferencePage.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: Does the Error Log contain a stack trace for that exception?

Comment: I added the Stacktrace from the m2e log at the end of the post. @nitind

Comment: That would be worth reporting as a bug to the m2e project. It's possible they didn't test it with Windows' specific kind of file locking. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=m2e

Comment: I get the same error on arch linux using eclipse 2021-03

Comment: I get the same error in macOS 10.14 with m2e-wtp-1.4.4.20201128-1705 under Eclipse 4.18. This was directly after installation in a fresh OS. I've never seen this error before.

Comment: I get the same error since eclipse 2020/12 till 2021/03. Did you get some solutions?

Comment: eclipse is bug haunted, needs more work

Comment: It's a issue on m2e ( [link](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/169) ) caused by maven indexer ( [MINDEXER-127](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MINDEXER-127) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally resolved by removing the system variable for *M2_HOME* that was pointing at an additional Maven installation on the system.

Eclipse seems to invoke this 2nd one during the reindexing operation thus leading to the *OverlappingFileLockException*.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and could not find any solution on internet. By luck, I found a way to just once open the same workspace in STS4 click on Window->Preferences->Maven->User Settings. I found the Local Repository automatically resolved the local repository and downloaded the artifacts in the given location.

Now open again the same workspace in Eclipse and it can readily resolve the local repository used in STS4.

**Also please note that I used a system variable to point the local repository location which was used in the User Settings file. So I found the solution to this while trying to resolve the issue of "Maven does not replace a variable in 'settings.xml' when it is invoked" which is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363514/maven-does-not-replace-a-variable-in-settings-xml-when-it-is-invoked)**